# Need SJCL to make the same encrypted AES 256 output when the PassPhrase is the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, cryptography, aes

I'm working on uploading file encrypted on the client side using Node.js, and I use SJCL (Stanford Javascript Crypto Library) to encrypt the file with Javascript.

But i noticed that the output or the result of the encryption is always different even with the same PassPhrase.

After few research i found that it's because the salt is random each time and i need to do a 'nosalt' (sorry I'm new to everything here cryptographie, Node.js)

How can I change my code (or SJCL code) to generate the exact encrypt output each time when the password is the same.

My app is based on "Cryptloader" project, you can find it here: https://github.com/Kryil/Cryptloader

Encrypt:

```
var part = file_queue[data["id"]].slice(start, end)

var reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = function(e)
{
var passwd = document.getElementById("password").value

console.log("Uploading arraybuffer of size " + e.target.result.byteLength)
var i32a = new Int32Array(e.target.result)

var out = i32a.toJSONArray()

console.log("crypting: " + out)

var crypted = sjcl.encrypt(passwd, out)

ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      "type": "fileslice",
      "data": {"id": data["id"], "slice": slice, "data": crypted}
}))
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(part)
```

Decrypt:

```
var decrypted = sjcl.decrypt(passwd, data["data"])

file_contents[file]["data"].push(new Int32Array(JSON.parse(decrypted)))
```

This is irrelevant question, but not all files upload correctly, some of them produce an error, but when i Change Int32Array to either Int16Array or Int8Array, it works for them but produce error for other files, what causes that and how to fix it.
The error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: ArrayBuffer length minus the byteOffset is not a multiple of the element size.
(Chrome Latest version, Win 7)
```

Comment: Why do you need that same keys (and plaintexts) produce identical ciphertexts? Do you want to compare them?

Comment: Yes, I want to use "convergent encryption" in my app to save space, that's why I want to do this, and since the cipher-text is different each time there's no way to compare them

Comment: Normally with convergent encryption you derive a (maybe keyed) hash from the message/file to use as an identifier (and another one as a key). Compare these identifiers, not the whole files. Have a look at the [\[convergent-encryption\]-tag on our sister site Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergent-encryption).

Comment: Yes this is we are dealing with the same user, what if another user want to store the same file, we can't predict the password this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just the `salt` that makes the cipher text different each time it's the `iv` too. But these are both security features that provide semantic security that you really should not disable and also shouldn't need to disable, because the salt and iv can be included with the cipher text there isn't anything keeping you from decryption at a later time by using a random `salt` or `iv`.

That said the `encrypt` function you are using lets you pass your own filled out parameters for the crypto including `salt` and `iv`, but to hard-code those to a fixed value (I would like to **strongly** point out)  is **not** the api intention and an abuse of the api.

Comment: I want to use "convergent encryption" in my app to save space, that's why I want to do this

Comment: if it's file level convergent, then I would think you would just hash the plaintext with sha256 store that with the ciphertext to match up with plaintext duplicates.

Comment: As you can see it's a Block-level convergent, and even if i detect that this file is duplicate in my disk with the hash, I can't give access to someone else since i don't know what was the PassPhrase

Comment: I don't think block level convergent encryption exists, you could de-duplicate cipher text, which would work without having the same key. You could do do convergent encryption on chunks but you'd still be hashing and still have not be able to without the key, and the benefit seems suspect. Anyway this is out side the scope of the question, I suggest asking about convergent encryption on crypto.stackexchange, because this is not how you go about doing it.